# Error: No provider for AuthInterceptor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement an http interceptor using the new HttpClient in Angular 4.3, but I keep getting the error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AuthInterceptor!

This is what I have in my app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
],
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
        { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
        { path: "**", component: NotFoundComponent }
    ]),

    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
],
providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useExisting: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
]
};
```

I've looked into all the articles with the error "No provider for CustomService", and they all refer to making sure that the service is added to the providers list in app.module which I think I've done.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `useExisting`? That is for aliasing an existing dependency token. Unless something is already providing something under the token `AuthInterceptor` it will fail. Try adding `AuthInterceptor` to your `providers` property.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I followed a tutorial on implementing interceptors, but didn't realize useExisting meant it had to exist already. If you submit your comment as an answer to the question, I'm happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** change `useExisting` to `useClass` *or* add `AuthInterceptor` to your `providers` array if you want to inject it somewhere else explicitly.

There is likely an error in your provider configuration. Specifically you have registered your `AuthInterceptor` with the `useExisting` provider option.

What this does is register an alias for another, existing dependency injection provider under a new token.

The purpose of that would be to make a service which is already provided as `AuthInterceptor` available for injection via the token `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`.

Therefore, unless some other `ngModule` imported by your application* is already providing something under the token `AuthInterceptor`, it will fail.

To resolve the problem at hand, change `useExisting` to `useClass`, if `AuthInterceptor` is a class, otherwise change it to `useValue` or `useFactory` as needed.
Another option would be to add `AuthInterceptor` to your `providers` property you would do this if you want to inject it directly somewhere else.

*
**Note that all providers that are imported via *eagerly* loaded  `ngModules` are merged into a shared, global dependency injection container.**

Comment: @LamboJayapalan I made a slight mistake in this answer and I just updated it.